# extracting specific columns from a json array that contains single or multiple json objects in each row of the table column

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a column called action values. Each row contains a json array. Some rows have multiple json objects in them like so:

```
[{
    "action_destination": "y42",
    "action_target_id": "0",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase",
    "value": 67.67,
    "1d_click": 31.72,
    "7d_click": 67.67
}, {
    "action_destination": "y42",
    "action_target_id": "0",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content",
    "value": 107.85,
    "7d_click": 107.85
}, {
    "action_destination": "y42",
    "action_target_id": "0",
    "action_type": "omni_view_content",
    "value": 107.85,
    "7d_click": 107.85
}]
```

Other rows within the same action values column have single json objects like so:

```
[{
    "action_destination": "y42",
    "action_target_id": "0",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase",
    "value": 31.72,
    "1d_click": 31.72,
    "7d_click": 31.72
}]
```

How do I make use of BigQuery SQL to unflatten each row of the json column called action values and pull out the key of action_type, 1d_click and 7d_click whenever they occur and persist them as their own column names?

I have tried using JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in Big Query SQL but that only accounts for a situation where a row within the column has a single json array like the second example I gave and not multiple objects within one array. This is the problem I'm facing. Any row could contain one simple easy json array or it could contain an array with multiple nested arrays. I need to be able to have a solution that deals with both cases at the same time for each row